# How to count number of rows by 2 columns while ignoring the duplicates from a 3rd column?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a data.table that by 2 of the columns (works) while also trying to ignore the duplicate rows (3rd column)

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Result
a       x       y       2
a       x       y       2   <- row should be ignored from count
b       x       y       2
a       t       y       1
a       t       i       1
```

I've tried dropping the columns going in, but I don't really know how to chain commands.

```
dt[, Result:= .N, by = .(Col2, Col3)]
```

Comment: Result  := .N, gives 3, instead of 2 unless you are using a different dataset?  Are you looking for `setDT(df1)[, Result := uniqueN(Col1), .(Col2, Col3)]` Not clear though

Comment: Do you consider a row as a duplicated when it has the same values from Col1 to Col3 as a different row?

Comment: a row is a duplicate and it should not get counted if value from Col1 is the same.
In the example above, Result is the expected result so it's 2 instead of 3 as the 2nd row should not be counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to get the unique number of elements in 'Col1'.  It can be done with `uniqueN` on 'Col1' after grouping by 'Col2' and 'Col3'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Result := uniqueN(Col1), .(Col2, Col3)][]
#      Col1 Col2 Col3 Result
#1:    a    x    y      2
#2:    a    x    y      2
#3:    b    x    y      2
#4:    a    t    y      1
#5:    a    t    i      1
```

Comment: it works. I've tried before with unique but didn't know about uniqueN